# dwm doesn't load fontawesome

Tags: fonts, dwm

I want to set up icons for my tags in dwm. I have downloaded the `ttf-font-awesome` package with `sudo pacman -S ttf-font-awesome` and I changed this line in my `config.h` of dwm:

```
static const char *fonts[] = { "FontAwesome:size=16", "consolas:size=16" };
```

But it still doesn't work. Some icons show up correctly, while others show up slightly or even completely different. I copied the unicode glyph from fontawesome.com and added it to my `*tags` array in `config.h`. Did I miss something? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I had a Nerd font loaded also, and this font caused the icons to be loaded differently from what I expected. I removed the ner font and everything worked just fine.